# Using the uwp button on the right side of the I want to put textbox

Tags: xaml, button, uwp, position, c++-cx

How can I display a textbox beside a button like in this picture?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you *tried anything* so far?

Answer (score 1):

A [Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx) would be suitable here.

```
<Button Content="Edit">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Right">
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>

            <TextBox Width="250" Height="100" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Play around with the styles to get the appearance you want.